# How to create enum method

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum : `public enum Color { RED, YELLOW; }`.
And I want to create a method that returns the opposite color of the actual one. So if I have RED, my method returns YELLOW. But I don't know the process to follow to do that.
First step : `public Color opposite() { return ??? }`

Comment: Do you know how to write an if statement? Or a switch?

Comment: yes I know but I actually don't know what to put in it... I first thought of putting this.color.equals(...), but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this element is RED, you want to return YELLOW; otherwise you want to return RED. So

```
public enum Color {
    RED, YELLOW;
    public Color opposite() {
        if (this==Color.RED) {
            return Color.YELLOW;
        }
        return Color.RED;
    }
}
```

The `opposite()` method can be written more concisely as:

```
public Color opposite() {
    return (this==Color.RED ? Color.YELLOW : Color.RED);
}
```

or, if you want to allow for more enum values, as:

```
public Color opposite() {
    switch (this) {
        case RED: return Color.YELLOW;
        case YELLOW: return Color.RED;
        // other possible values
    }
    // required for compiler
    return null;
}
```

As [Holger suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509596/how-to-create-enum-method/71509756?noredirect=1#comment126403009_71509756), Java 12 onwards supports [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html), which offer a cleaner alternative:

```
public Color opposite() {
    return switch (this) {
        case RED -> Color.YELLOW;
        case YELLOW -> Color.RED;
    };
}
```

Comment: Oh I see how the grammar works now. This'll help me with my other methods... Thanks you :)

Comment: In recent Java versions, you can write `return switch(this) { case RED -> Color.YELLOW; case YELLOW -> Color.RED; };` without the need for a dummy default case.

Comment: @Holger Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **switch** for this.

```
 public class Main {
    enum Color {
        RED,
        YELLOW;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public Color opposite() {
        Color myColor = Color.RED;
        return switch (myColor) {
            case RED -> Color.YELLOW;
            case YELLOW -> Color.RED;
        };
    }

}
```

If you prefer to use **if statement** instead of switch. You can try this instead

```
public Color opposite() {
        Color myColor = Color.RED;
        if (myColor == Color.RED) {
            return Color.YELLOW;
        } else  if (myColor == Color.YELLOW) {
            return Color.RED;
        }
        return null;
    }
```